# My first return value inside a function is not returning anything

Tags: c

So I have a function which controls the turn taking of a player, and I want it to return FAILURE when the player unsuccessfully takes a turn. (The game is connect 4). I obviously want it to return success when the turn is valid, however.... Even when I return SUCCESS it's requiring two return SUCCESS to return a single success. Here is the code:

```
enum input_result take_turn(struct player * current,
    enum cell_contents board[][BOARDWIDTH])
{
/***************** Logic for Human player ******************/
if(current->type == HUMAN)
{
    printf("human");
    return SUCCESS;
}

/**************** Logic for Computer player ****************/
else if(current->type == COMPUTER)
{   
    printf("computer");
    return SUCCESS;
} 
return SUCCESS;
}
```

And it's called by this:

```
struct player * play_game(struct player * human , 
    struct player* computer)
{
while(counter < 30)
{
    take_turn(current, board);

    /* Only swap if take turn was success */
    if(take_turn(current, board) == SUCCESS)
    {
        swap_players(&current, &other);
        display_board(board);
    }

    counter++;
}

return NULL;
}
```

The only thing I can think that may be ruining this is my:

```
enum input_result
{
/**
 * the input was valid
 **/
SUCCESS,
/**
 * the input was not valld
 **/
FAILURE,
/**
 * the user requested to return to the menu either by pressing enter on
 * an empty line or pressing ctrl-d on an empty line
 **/
RTM=-1
};
```

I'm unsure why take_turn(current, board) is being called twice when the only possible outcome is for the if statement to be entered as every possible return value is SUCCESS. Does anyone have any idea why this may happen?
My output is printing:

HumanHuman

ComputerComputer

HumanHuman

ComputerComputer

and so on... showing that it's going through it twice before a success is registered.

Comment: Just for clarification: you're wondering why `take_turn` still is executed in the if-clause although it can only return `SUCCESS` and the code within the if-clause **must** be executed?

Comment: Yes, I am wondering why it is not entering the if statement and calling the swap of players when the only possible return value being returned is SUCCESS

Comment: I've voted to close this question as a typographical error that will not be able to be duplicated (once the OP removes the extra call to `take_turn()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
while(counter < 30)
{
    take_turn(current, board);

    /* Only swap if take turn was success */
    if(take_turn(current, board) == SUCCESS)
```

You're calling `take_turn()` twice.

Comment: I did not realise that having it in the if statement like that would call it again... I can't believe i just spent like 3 hours trying to figure this out... duhhhhhh

thanks so much

Comment: how did you reach this conclusion when even the Op's question does not tell how is he getting the said output ? or I just happened to have misread the question?

Comment: @rahultyagi it's a logical explanation for what the OP said his output contains and why he feels it's wrong. He shows the code that generates that output and he doesn't expect the output... the code justifies it though.

Comment: Yeah it works completely fine when i remove the first call, thanks again, sorry i can't upvote the answers as I don't have the required rep

Comment: @Ryan you can upvote them in a few minutes I think, but as this question isn't likely to help other readers in the future, deleting the question is reasonable too.

Comment: yeah I can see that too but still I don't think the question is self explanatory.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't delete the question as it has answers posted to it

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice that you are calling take_turn twice in your loop? Once without looking for the return value, and another in your if statement. get rid of the first one.